# Debian statistics - cpu, memory, hdd

Tags: linux, debian, dedicated-server, command

I'm wondering how can I get my dedicated server avarage statistics for last month/ week.

I used sysstat and sar to report my logs, but they are seems to be too much I'm interested about averege final number.

Any ideas how can I get last month/week avarege CPU usage, memory usage, HDD gain and your suggestions? Anuthing can which could be usefull?

I use htop sometimes but those are current moment statistics.

Comment: Write a script to do what you want with the sar data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script, which runs hourly or daily (by using crontab). The script calculate average value from systat log, then write to another file and clear logs to start a new period.

Comment: yeah, I think I tried that (maybe I wrote it wrong) and it looks like there's a ton of useless stats and avarege stats I'm interested about.

Crontab below:
    56 23 * * * root sar -o /home/test.log -A 1 3

    58 23 * * * root sar -A -f /home/test.log >> /home/cma/sardata-`date "+\%d-\%m-\%Y"`.txt

I definitely looking for something more friendly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan on sar either so I use nmon for this . 
Have a look at http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php

Or, another option I would suggest is Graphite .
http://graphite.wikidot.com/

Hope this helps!